# Generating JSON request manually, returned HTML causing issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am generating my JSON manually, and I even escaped for quotes with a preceding backslash.  It is causing me problems.

My HTML returned looks something like:

```
<div class="blah"><div class="a2">This is just a test!  I hope this work's man!</div></div>


string json = "MY HTML HERE";
json = json.Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```

Is there more to replace than just the double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
json = json.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Please post more details, where is this code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be json.Replace("\"", "\\\"")?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to the [JSON spec](http://json.org/) a valid string value is 'any Unicode character except " or \ or a control-character.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have line breaks in the strings for the json?  Sometimes this breaks up many browsers.  I usually change " to \", \ to \, and cr/lf to \n.  The line break is not part of the json specification as per json.org but most javascript interpreters can deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't encode JSON by hand - use the serializer!

```
string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    .Serialize(html);
```